# How to insert a condition of one line into another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, genetic

I'm with a challenge in python/pandas script.
My data is a gene expression table, which is organized as follow:

[image]

Basically, Index 0 contain the both conditions studied, while Index 1 has the information about the gene identified between the samples.

Then, I would like to produce a table with index 0 and 1 close together, as follow:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things, such as generate a list of index 0 to join in index 1...

Save me, guys, please!

Thank you

Comment: Can you give your data as text output we can create a dataframe one, you can just give a slice df[0:1].to_dict or something.

Comment: I get the 3 head lines:

,,,,Cond1,,,Cond2,,
Gene name,Description,Foldchange,Anova,Sample 1,Sample 2,Sample 3,Sample 4,Sample 5,Sample 6
HK1,Hexokinase,Infinity,0.05,1213,1353,14356,0,0,0

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first row of column names are in row 0, and your second column names are in row 1 try this:

```
df.columns = [f'{c1}.{c2}'.strip('.') for c1,c2 in zip(df.loc[0], df.loc[1])]

df.loc[2:]
```

Should look like this

[image]

Comment: Hey Myccha, thank you for help!
But it doesn't work, 
I don't know if it can help, but here is the .csv version of file: 


,,,,Cond1,,,Cond2,,
Gene name,Description,Foldchange,Anova,Sample 1,Sample 2,Sample 3,Sample 4,Sample 5,Sample 6
HK1,Hexokinase,Infinity,0.05,1213,1353,14356,0,0,0


I would like it was


,,,,Cond1,,,Cond2,,
Gene name,Description,Foldchange,Anova,Sample 1.Cond1,Sample 2.Cond1,Sample 3.Cond1,Sample 4.Cond2,Sample 5.Cond2,Sample 6.Cond2
HK1,Hexokinase,Infinity,0.05,1213,1353,14356,0,0,0


When I applied your script, there was no change :/

Comment: Have you read it as a pandas dataframe? If so, can you do `df.to_clipboard()` and paste the output here. P.S. you can also use `pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6 Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8 Unnamed: 9 Unnamed: 10
0     Cond1   Cond2   
1 Gene name Description Foldchange Anova Sample 1 Sample 2 Sample 3 Sample 4 Sample 5 Sample 6 
2 HK1 Hexokinase Infinity 0.05 1213 1353 14356 0 0 0

Comment: See edits to the answer above. You can use `pd.read_csv(file.csv, header=False).fillna('')` to get the file into pandas. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP's comment, I change the `add_suffix` function.

construct the dataframe

```
s1 = "Gene name,Description,Foldchange,Anova,Sample 1,Sample 2,Sample 3,Sample 4,Sample 5,Sample 6".split(",")
s2 = "HK1,Hexokinase,Infinity,0.05,1213,1353,14356,0,0,0".split(",")

df = pd.DataFrame(s2).T
df.columns = s1
```

define a function, (change the funcition according to different situations)

```
def add_suffix(x):
    try:
        flag = int(x[-1])
    except:
        return x
    if flag <= 4:
        return x + '.Conditon1'
    else:
        return x + '.Condition2'
```

and then assign the columns

```
cols = df.columns.to_series().apply(add_suffix)
df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Hey lambda, thank you for help me! But this code doesn't work as well.
In this link are write my csv file, if you want to try again:
pastebin.com/Td0CPP5v